# Android Immersive mode not working properly with SlidingMenu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-fullscreen

Hi guys I have a problem with android Immersive mode, the problem is that it works perfect with every activity I have except one that have SlidingMenu setup.

Here is my code that I use.

```css
    @Override
 protected void onResume() {

  super.onResume();
  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
 }
```

Here is my ScreenShot that Immersive mode works perfect.
[image: Activity With Immersive mode is OK]
And Here is my ScreenShot from activity that has SlidingMenu and rises problem with Immersive mode.(Look for empty black space in up and bottom)
[image: Activity With SlidingMenu]

Comment: I encountered the same problem with you. But I have no idea what happened. My temp solution is stopping using sliding menu library. I can draw full screen without sliding menu library.

Comment: I found a solution. You can rewrite some code in sliding menu library. Please refer to this url.

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680